# Separating from a List of Dictionaries in Python with optional parameters

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am attempting to match a very long list of Python dictionaries.  What I'm looking for is to append dicts from this list into a new list based on the values of the keys of the dict. An example of what I have is:

A list of 1000+ dictionaries structured like this:

```
{'regions': ['north','south'],
'age':35,
'name':'john',
'cars':['ford','kia']}
```

I want to sort and match through this list using almost all keys and append the matching ones to a new list.  Sometimes I might be searching with only `age`, where as other times I will be searching with `regions` & `name`, all the way to searching with all keys like `age`, `name`, `regions`, & `cars` because all parameters to search with are optional.

I currently have used for loops to sort through it, but as I add more and more optional parameters, it gets slower and more complex.  Is there an easier way to accompany what I am doing?

An example of what the user would send is:

```
regions: north
age: 10
```

And it would return a list of all dictionaries with **north** as a `region` and **10** as `age`

Comment: It would be great to add the required output and code you have tried so far so we can analyze efficiently what actually you're trying to do.

Comment: is this data currently stored in a relational or document model database? that could make it easier to deal with

Comment: In general, to make searching faster, you need to keep and maintain a sorted index for the fields you want to perform searches on. As you add `dict`'s to this list, you need to also add entries to all of the indexes (in their sorted position). Databases handle a lot of the boilerplate and complexity of indexing and searching automatically. You would probably be better off using a database to store and search these records instead of trying to create your own using lists and dicts.

Comment: All dictionaries are stored in a local list that is updated every couple of hours

Comment: This may or may not be technically feasible depending on your current implementation, but trying to do this in this method is a boondoggle.  You may succeed with some very nested code, but it won't be extensible.  You'd be better off using a database.  I used to hate it when people on here would tell me the same thing, but they were right too.

Comment: Currently my nested code is a massive mess, and I was actually sorting perfectly until I needed at also sort for 'age', I was just wondering if there was an easier way that was faster & more pleasing to the eyes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a code to do this

```py
test = [
    {
        'regions': ['south'],
        'age':35,
        'name':'john',
        'cars':['ford']
    },
    {
        'regions': ['north'],
        'age':15,
        'name':'michael',
        'cars':['kia']
    },
    {
        'regions': ['north','south'],
        'age':20,
        'name':'terry',
        'cars':['ford','kia']
    },
    {
        'regions': ['East','south'],
        'age':35,
        'name':'user',
        'cars':['other','kia']
    },
    {
        'regions': ['East','south'],
        'age':75,
        'name':'john',
        'cars':['other']
    }
]



def Finder(inputs: list, regions: list = None, age: int = None, name: str = None, cars: list = None) -> list:
    output = []
    for input in inputs:
        valid = True

        if regions != None and valid: valid = all(i in input["regions"] for i in regions)
        if age != None and valid: valid = input["age"] == age
        if name != None and valid: valid = input["name"] == name
        if cars != None and valid: valid = all(i in input["cars"] for i in cars)

        if valid:
            output.append(input)

    return output

print(Finder(test))
print(Finder(test, age = 25))
print(Finder(test, regions = ["East"]))
print(Finder(test, cars = ["ford","kia"]))
print(Finder(test, name = "john", regions = ["south"]))
```

This function just checks all parameters and check if the input is valid, and he puts all valid inputs in an output list

Answer (score 1):

I think this one is pretty open ended, especially because you suggest that you want this to be extensible as you add more keys etc. and haven't really discussed your operational requirements. But here are a few thoughts:

#### Third party modules

Are these dictionaries going to get any more nested? Or is it going to always be 'key -> value' or 'key -> [list, of, values]'?

If you can accept a chunky dependency, you might consider something like `pandas`, which we normally think of as representing tables, but which can certainly manage nesting to some degree.

For example:

```py
from functools import partial
from pandas import DataFrame
from typing import Dict


def matcher(comparator, target=None) -> bool:
    """
    matcher

    Checks whether a value matches or contains a target
    (won't match if the target is a substring of the value)

    """
    if target == comparator:  # simple case, return True immediately
        return True
    if isinstance(comparator, str):
        return False  # doesn't match exactly and string => no match
    try:  # handle looking in collections
        return target in comparator
    except TypeError:  # if it fails, you know there's no match
        return False


def search(data: DataFrame, query: Dict) -> DataFrame:
    """
    search

    Pass in a DataFrame and a query in the form of a dictionary
    of keys and values to match, for example:
        {"age": 42, "regions": "north", "cars": "ford"}

    Returns a matching subset of the data

    """
    # each element of the resulting list is a boolean series
    # corresponding to a dictionary key
    masks = [
        data[key].map(partial(matcher, target=value)) for key, value in query.items()
    ]

    # collapse the masks down to a single boolean series indicating
    # whether ALL conditions are met for each record
    mask = pd.concat(masks, axis="columns").all(axis="columns")

    return data.loc[mask]


if __name__ == "__main__":

    data = DataFrame(your_big_list)

    query = {"age": 35, "regions": "north", "cars": "ford"}

    results = search(data, query)

    list_results = results.to_dict(orient="records")
```

Here `list_results` would restore the filtered data to the original format, if that's important to you.

I found that the `matcher` function had to be surprisingly complicated, I kept thinking of edge-cases (like: we need to support searching in a collection, but `in` can also find substrings, which isn't what we want ... unless it is, of course!).

But at least all that logic is walled off in there. You could write a series of unit tests for it, and if you extend your schema in future you can then alter the function accordingly and check the tests still pass.

The `search` function then is purely for nudging `pandas` into doing what you want with the `matcher`.

#### `match case`

In Python 3.10 the new `match case` statement might allow you to very cleanly encapsulate the matching logic.

#### Performance

A pretty fundamental issue here is that if you care about performance (and I got the sense that this was secondary to maintainability for you) then

1. the bigger the data get, the slower things will be
2. python is already not fast, generally speaking

You could possibly improve things by building some sort of index for your data. Ultimately, however, it's always going to be more reliable to use a specialist tool. That's going to be *some sort* of database.

The precise details will depend on your requirements. e.g. are these data going to become horribly unstructured? Are any fields going to be text that will need to be properly indexed in something like Elasticsearch/Solr?

A really light-touch solution that you could implement in the short term with Python would be to

- chuck that data into SQLite
- rely on SQL for the searching

I am suggesting SQLite since it runs out-of-the-box and just in a single local file:

```py
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

engine = create_engine("sqlite:///mydb.sql")

# ... that's it, we can now connect to a SQLite DB/the 'mydb.sql' file that will be created
```

... but the drawback is that it won't support array-like data. Your options are:

1. use postgreSQL instead and take the hit of running a DB with more firepower
2. normalise those data

I don't think option 2 would be too difficult. Something like:

```
REGIONS
id | name
----------
1  | north
2  | south
3  | east
4  | west

CUSTOMERS
id | age | name
---------------
...

REGION_LINKS
customer_id | region_id
-----------------------
     1      |     1
     1      |     2
```

I've called the main data table 'customers' but you haven't mentioned what these data really represent, so that's more by way of example.

Then your SQL queries could get built and executed using `sqlalchemy`'s ORM capabilities.